# By default, does gcc link to static or dynamic standard library?

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic, static, linker

Ex:

```
gcc source-file
```

I think it is dynamic but I'm not sure. Is it system dependent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is technically system dependent, but on *most* systems you're likely to develop for, the answer is "dynamic".

A few systems (mostly very old, embedded, or otherwise specialized) do not support dynamic linking *at all*, but most developers are unlikely to care about those systems. On those systems, the linker will of course default to linking statically (unless whoever did the port screwed up :)).

Some systems also do not offer static versions of their standard libraries, so you *can't* statically link them.

On many systems (especially any typical Linux system), you probably have a utility called `ldd`. You can use `ldd <file>` to check if it's dynamically linked to the standard library (assuming you know for sure what the library is called, it's usually `libc` though).

Answer (score 1):

Most linkers prefer dynamic libraries to static when linking, but normally they have flags to explicitly specify the behaviour.  It's definitely system dependent - check your linker documentation for details.